# GlusterFS mounted volume not accessible from Windows through samba

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, samba, glusterfs

### Requirement

Creating a replicated shared drive with GlusterFS and have it accessible in Windows ActiveDirectory with the UNC path.

PS: All our servers are windows and in a single domain. Only GlusterFS servers are linux.

### What I've achieved so far

I have setup GlusterFS with:

- Two gluster nodes (GlusterFS: ver 3.3.2 - OS: CentOS release 6.4)
- A replicated volume (gvol1).
- gvol1, mounted on both the nodes (say at /mnt/gvol1).

Working FINE till this point. Any file created in the mounted volume (on any node) is replicated to the volume (and the underlying brick) on both the nodes.

I have ALSO installed and configured SAMBA on both the nodes. Joined both the machines to our windows domain. This looks FINE too. I had success with these tests:

- AD authentication - SUCCESS
- Sharing a folder from linux through SAMBA. And accessing through windows machines. - SUCCESS

### Problem

When I try to share the GlusterFS vol (mounted at /mnt/gvol1 on both the gluster nodes) through SAMBA. This is what happens:

- VIEWING the shared gluster volume in windows through UNC path (i.e. 'gvol1shared' is visible in \gnode1) - SUCCESS
- **ACCESSING the shared gluster volume in windows through UNC (i.e. opening \gnode1\gvol1shared) - FAILED**

I have tried various things but had no luck with this.

**Note:** I believe while testing GlusterFS couple of months ago, I did a work around for this issue. Instead of sharing the 'mounted volume' (i.e. /mnt/gvol1) through SAMBA, I shared the brick on one of the glusternodes (i.e. say /export/gluster/brick1). **And I believe it worked. BUT Now when I write anything directly to the brick it doesn't replicate it to other bricks.** So, I'm confused and doubt that it worked in first place. Or I need to change something to get this working too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to share and use

1. Other folders in the system
2. brick directories(I should tell you, that is not a very good idea. Gluster does not support writing into brick directories directly.)

as you have said above, then there is only one problem that I see.

Your FUSE mount permissions don't let user accessing the share through Samba to read/write on it.

Solution:

1. Mount the volume on /mnt/gvol1
2. Use chmod or posix acls to provide permissions to user on it.

Answer (score 0):

Writing directly to a brick is never supported: glusterfs process is the only one ever meant to touch a brick once it has been added to a volume.

These days, the simplest solutions is to use the `glusterfs` vfs module in Samba: there’s no need to mount the Gluster volume at all then. Samba ca directly access the data on it.